# Dynamically creating Multiple row radio buttons

Tags: android, android-layout, android-radiobutton

I'm creating  radio buttons dynamically based on the input .In my  case layout has fixed width and height is expandable. What i want is if the radio buttons exceeds the fixed layout width , then it should automatically arrange in next row . Is this possible or manually we have to do it for next row arrangment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using [FlowLayout](https://github.com/ApmeM/android-flowlayout) which automatically arranges `View` when it runs out of space.